# what should the payload look like for hasMany relation in ember data 1.0.0 beta 14.1?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with hierarchical relation like this:

```
 App.Question=DS.Model.extend({
  name:DS.attr('string'),
  childQuestions:DS.hasMany('question',{async:true}),
  parentQuestion:DS.attr('string')
});
```

My payload looks like this :

```
"questions":[
  {
    id:1,
    name:'question 1',
    childQuestions:[]
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:'question 2',
    childQuestions:[3]
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:'question 3',
    childQuestions:[],
    parentQuestion:2
  }
]
```

before with ember 1.5 and ember data beta 3, I was able to do :

```
var q = model.findBy('id','2');
console.log(q.get('childQuestions'));//would give me promiseArray with the child questions
```

but the same returns empty promise array that has nothing even when it resolves!!

Code with ember 1.5.0 and data-data 1.0.0 beta 3 : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zeqomitapi/1/

Code with ember 1.9.1 and data-data 1.0.0 beta 14.1 : http://jsbin.com/koyiqocoyi/1/

I could probably try out "EmbeddedRecordsMixin" but at this point we don't want to change anything in the rest api itself.

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data wants you to configure the `parentQuestion` relationship as a DS.belongsTo:

```
App.Question=DS.Model.extend({
  name:DS.attr('string'),
  childQuestions:DS.hasMany('question',{async:true}),
  parentQuestion:DS.belongsTo('question')
});
```

Updated and working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mubuji/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the answer.